# correctly set CMake variables when adding yaml-cpp to existing project

Tags: c++, cmake, yaml-cpp

I've added the `yaml-cpp` git repository as a submodule and add it to my CMake project using `add_subdirectory`.

Everything's fine but I have to set `YAML_CPP_INCLUDE_DIR` and `YAML_CPP_LIBRARIES` manually to use them for my own targets.

Because there is a file `yaml-cpp-config.cmake` (generated in the build folder) setting these variables I tried to just include it:

```
include("${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/yaml-cpp/yaml-cpp-config.cmake")
```

but then I get:

```
CMake Error at /bla/bla/build/yaml-cpp/yaml-cpp-config.cmake:11 (include):
  The file

/bla/bla/aml-cpp/yaml-cpp-targets.cmake

  was generated by the export() command.  It may not be used as the argument
  to the include() command.  Use ALIAS targets instead to refer to targets by
  alternative names.
```

I really don't understand this message. How would I provide my targets with the `yaml-cpp` include directories and libraries without having to set a hard coded variable?

I'm not searching for a way to *correctly* `include()` the file in case it doesn't have to be done. I'm just interested in how I *should* provide the desired information to my targets.

Unfortunately `yaml-cpp` seems to not make use of `target_include_directories()` which would set the include directories automatically where needed.

Comment: This is a developer warning and can be controlled with CMake policy [CMP0024](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/policy/CMP0024.html). The reasoning for the warning: "CMake 2.8.12 and lower allowed use of the include() command with the result of the export() command. This relies on the assumption that the export() command has an immediate effect at configure-time during a cmake run. ... Future refactoring will change the effect of the export() command to be executed at generate-time. Use ALIAS targets instead in cases where the goal is to refer to targets by another name".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [description](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/export.html) of `export` command:

> Create a file <filename> that may be included by **outside** projects to import targets from the current project’s build tree.

Note to "outside" word: this is why you get the error message while trying to include the file from the *same* project, which issues `export` command.

Correct way to use `yaml-cpp-config.cmake` file would be building `yaml-cpp` *outside* of your project. For example, you may use `ExternalProject_Add` in conjunction with `execute_process` for build `yaml-cpp` as part of configuration stage of your project, see more about this approach [here](https://crascit.com/2015/07/25/cmake-gtest/).

Then you may include given file to your project with `find_package`:

```
find_package(yaml-cpp PATHS <yaml-cpp-build-dir>)
```

---

Note, that `yaml-cpp-config.cmake` in *binary* directory describes **build state** of `yaml-cpp` project.

If you want to *install* libraries/executables from your project, you are better to *install* `yaml-cpp`, and include corresponded file from its *installation* directory:

```
find_package(yaml-cpp PATHS <yaml-cpp-install-dir>)
```

Comment: That's not what I was hoping to hear but probably it's the correct approach :)

Comment: What should I include as the libraries? I tried the following but is did not work:  set(YAML_CPP_INCLUDE_DIRS
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/gtsam/3rdparty/yaml-cpp/include/yaml-cpp
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/gtsam/3rdparty/yaml-cpp/include
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/gtsam/3rdparty/yaml-cpp/src
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/gtsam/3rdparty/yaml-cpp)
find_package(yaml-cpp PATHS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/gtsam/3rdparty/yaml-cpp/build)
include_directories(${YAML_CPP_INCLUDE_DIRS})

Comment: It is described in `YAMLCPPConfig.cmake` file which variables are set as a result of `find_package(yaml-cpp)`. Please, create new question post and describe your problem there, comments are not suitable for new questions.

Comment: I've encountered this problem as well. So from what I understand the easy solution is still to hard-code the paths? The actual "solutions" seem highly stupid.

Comment: @tambre: Using `add_subdirectory(yaml-cpp)` means that you want to treat `yaml-cpp` as a *collection of targets and files* (with hardcoded paths). If you want to treat `yaml-cpp` as *unified thing*, you need to **install it**, either within your project (`ExternalProject_Add` in conjunction with `execute_process`) or as a *prerequisite* to your project. After installation, you may use `find_package(yaml-cpp)`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I see. Might be worth noting that this can be fixed easily by disabling the yaml-cpp-targets script, which specifies yaml-cpp as an IMPORTED target. I also created an issue regarding this: https://github.com/jbeder/yaml-cpp/issues/439